# Как вывести полный путь к выбранному файлу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Код - выбор файла, вывод его имени и пути нахождения. Имя выбранного файла определяется и выводится. Проблема в определении пути к выбранному файлу. Выводится путь где находится скрипт. Подскажите, как определить путь выбираемого файла?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import os

root=Tk()
root.withdraw()

try:
    file = fd.askopenfilename()      
except:
    file = ''
    pass

file_name = os.path.basename(file) 
file_path = os.path.abspath(file_name) 

if file == '':
    pass
else:
    print(file_name)
    print(file_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы лишние действия делаете, `askopenfilename()` - сразу возвращает путь, где находится выбранный файл.

> **askopenfilename()**: открывает диалоговое окно для выбора файла и
> возвращает путь к выбранному файлу. Если файл не выбран, возвращается
> пустая строка ""

Именно это значение в вашем коде не выводится на печать.

Попробуйте:

```
file = fd.askopenfilename()   
print(file)
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо!